# Optimizing a mysql query for a specific sql script

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I want to query a table that has around 70 million records. The query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM tweetentities 
 WHERE applicationId = 6 
   AND isRetweet = false 
   AND (CURDATE() <= DATE_ADD(tweetDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

What I want to do is I try to get older records than 7 days on the table with other criteria like appId and isRetweet. The main point that I'd like to know is that does the query work faster if I request just the necessary columns rather than all columns with " * " symbol. Or if you have better idea to optimize the query above, please tell me this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note:  Your version of the query gets tweets within the last week, not tweets more than a week old.  The sign is reversed if you want older tweets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tweetentities
WHERE applicationId = 6 AND
      isRetweet = false AND
      (CURDATE() <= DATE_ADD(tweetDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

You should rewrite it as:

```
SELECT *
FROM tweetentities
WHERE applicationId = 6 AND
      isRetweet = false AND
      tweetDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

Then build the index `tweetentities(applicationId, isRetweet, tweetDate)`.

Comment: @mehmetGokhanBakal, Gordon is correct, especially on the date component.  If you apply the date_add() to the column, the index can be utilized, but by swapping and computing against the current date, it can.

Comment: Ok, I have almost 70M records and creating a compound index with applicationId, isRetweet, tweetDate columns will take too long time, this makes me worried about time.

Comment: You can try creating the index, it might not take as much time as you are thinking it will.